# Why is Unity using property injection when resolving a concrete type?

Tags: .net, unity-container

I have an interface:

```
 public interface IFoo{ 
     string Bar{ get; set; } 
 }
```

and an implementation of the interface

```
public class RealFoo{
    public string Bar{ get; set; }
    public string Qux{ get; set; }
}
```

I have configured unity, via the configuration file, to resolve IFoo to RealFoo, using property injection:

```
<register type="Namespace.IFoo, Assembly" mapTo="Namespace.RealFoo, Assembly">
    <property name="Qux" value="somevalue" />
</register>
```

If I call Resolve(typeof(RealFoo)), my instance has .Qux set to "somevalue". How is this possible? Is this expected behavior? I understand that if I call Resolve(typeof( IFoo )) that .Qux would be set to "somevalue", but cannot explain how resolving the concrete type would set .Qux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using unity registration, and injection parameters/constructors you are defining those for the type it is mapped to. I don't use configuration files in unity, but in code it allows you to do the following:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IFoo, FooOne>("FooOne" new InjectionProperty("Qux", "somevalue"));
unityContainer.RegisterType<IFoo, FooTwo>("FooTwo", new InjectionProperty("Qux", "anothervalue"));
```

Meaning different concrete types can have different injection parameters/properties. In unity, unless the registrations are named, the last registered concrete injection parameters are used.

Consider the following:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IFoo, FooOne>(new InjectionProperty("Qux", "somevalue"));
unityContainer.RegisterType<FooOne>(new InjectionProperty("Qux", "anothervalue"));
```

If i then did either `unityContainer.Resolve<IFoo>()` or `unityContainer.Resolve<FooOne>()` both would have "anothervalue" injected into "Qux", as it resolves both to a `FooOne` instance and the last registration injected "Qux" as "anothervalue".

Comment: Thanks, Lukazoid. I accepted your answer. Of course, that's how it IS working, and when you explain it, it makes sense. I thought that might be the case initially, but wasn't sure it wasn't a bug, because unityContainer.IsRegistered<FooOne> returns false if FooOne is only on the 'to' side of the mapping registration (e.g. @mapTo), but unityContainer.IsRegistered<FooOne> returns true if it is on the 'from' side of a mapping registration (e.g. @type).

Answer (score 0):

What else do you expect it to do? It injects dependencies for you. `Qux` is a dependency. If you don't want it to do that, tell it. This behavior is consistent with its behavior for constructors.

Comment: I suspect that you have not read the question carefully. The author is expecting to see `Qux` initialized when `IFoo` is passed to the resolved, but not when `RealFoo` is passed.

Comment: I read it perfectly fine. I suspect you didn't read my answer carefully. His expectation is wrong.